# jsonata filter by "outside" property

Tags: jsonata

I need to filter values of `list2` by property of `list1` as such:

JSON:

```
{
  "list1": [
    {"b":1, "list2": [{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]},
    {"b":2, "list2": [{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]},
    {"b":3, "list2": [{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]}
  ]
}
```

JSONata:

```
{
    "result": $$.list1.{ 
        "v": list2[a=b].{
            "v":a
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is - I don't know how to reference `b` property of `list1` in filter `list2[a=b]`

https://try.jsonata.org/dxPC5s-zM

Expected result is:

```
{
  "result": [
    {"v":1},
    {"v":2},
    {"v":3}
  ]
}
```

I know example is "stupid" but it simply illustrate problem.
I was wondering if some temp variables could be used to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok I found solution with temp. variables:

JSONata:

```
{
    "result": $$.list1.(
        $b := b; /* temp var. */
        { 
           "v": list2[a=$b].{
              "v":a
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'parent' operator to reference this 'outside' property. So if you are within the context of the list2 array, you can refer to the 'b' property of list1 using:

`list1.list2[a = %.b]`

See https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-parent